# Missing socket.AF_BLUETOOTH in Anaconda Python?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, anaconda

I'm trying to use socket.AF_BLUETOOTH as explained here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html

I have Python 3.3.5 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64) on Mac OS X 10.10.2

and the socket module doesn't seem to contain any AF_BLUETOOTH reference:

```
In [1]: import socket
In [2]: socket.AF
socket.AF_APPLETALK  socket.AF_INET       socket.AF_IPX        socket.AF_SNA        socket.AF_UNIX       
socket.AF_DECnet     socket.AF_INET6      socket.AF_ROUTE      socket.AF_SYSTEM     socket.AF_UNSPEC
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The docs say:

> Depending on the system and the build options, various socket families are supported by this module.

And from this bit in Modules/socketmodule.c:

```
#if (defined(HAVE_BLUETOOTH_H) || defined(HAVE_BLUETOOTH_BLUETOOTH_H)) && !defined(__NetBSD__) && !defined(__DragonFly__)
#define USE_BLUETOOTH 1
```

you'll want to make sure that HAVE_BLUETOOTH_H or USE_BLUETOOTH get set true during compilation. Which one depends by the location of your headers file. They can be in `/usr/include` or `/usr/include/bluetooth`. You can check your current settings via:

```py
import sysconfig
print sysconfig.get_config_vars()['HAVE_BLUETOOTH_H']
```

I'm guessing that returns 0 for you currently. A hint from pyconfig.h.in:

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the <bluetooth/bluetooth.h> header file. */
#undef HAVE_BLUETOOTH_BLUETOOTH_H
```

so you should make sure that `bluetooth/bluetooth.h` header file is present on your system and available in your search path during compilation.

Comment: I've been stung by this myself...  If you're using Ubuntu/Debian then you'll want to install the `libbluetooth-dev` package before compiling python.

Comment: @Josh Kupershmidt: it does return 0 in my case. Do I have to compile python from source to solve it?

Comment: @Fra Yes, you will have to recompile AND make sure you've got that bluetooth.h header file available during recompilation. This may be tricky on OS X -- apparently OS X provides a [Bluetooth.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Kernel/Reference/kernel_Bluetooth_header_reference/) header, but note that's an uppercase "B" and I suspect it wouldn't get picked up. You may just have an easier time on Linux as Tim Tisdall suggests.

Comment: To set a flag use `#define HAVE_BLUETOOTH_BLUETOOTH_H 1` in case the `bluetooth.h` file in in `/usr/include` or `#define HAVE_BLUETOOTH_H 1` in case the `bluetooth.h` file in in `/usr/include`. Don't set them all, otherwise the build will fail.

Answer (score 2):

PF_BLUETOOTH is an protocol family implemented by Linux’s bluetooth module (from BlueZ). On Linux, you create a L2CAP socket and use socket syscalls to communicate with the device (connect, bind, read, write), and the addresses have address family AF_BLUETOOTH. But this is a Linux-only socket type.

On the Mac, you need to use the [CoreBluetooth API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295) (which uses XPC messages to the blued daemon) instead to communicate to a Bluetooth LE device.

I’m not aware of a Python wrapper for CoreBluetooth on OS X, but if you want to see how it might look see the node.js libraries [bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno) or [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble). Actually these libraries use the internal XPC messages which might not be too stable instead of the public API.