# How do I activate socket.AF_BLUETOOTH in Python3.6?

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Python3.6 standard installation in Windows and I try to do

```
>>>import socket
>>>socket.AF_BLUETOOTH
```

The system responds with

```
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'
```

me and a colleague spend already some time reading forums. I scanned through socket.py in PythonPath\Lib\ but there is as well no mentioning of AF_BLUETOOTH. There is a stackoverflow thread [Missing socket.AF_BLUETOOTH in Anaconda Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107537/missing-socket-af-bluetooth-in-anaconda-python) which talks about recompiling Python with some changes in some .header files.

Can anyone give a bit more details how to get to a running Python/socket/bluetooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it's not available on windows port:

OK with 3.6.7 on linux

KO with 3.6.7 on w10

It would be nice to have a warning in the doc, I've found it...

Comment: Not available on Python 3.7.6 Anaconda / Ubuntu 18.04